# SQL Left Outer Join with a One to Many Row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. An account table and a transactions table. I want to list all accounts with their **last transaction**. Need a left join since cases may exist with no transaction.

I have something like

```
select * from Account ac left join Transaction trans on ac.id = trans.acc_id
```

But that will list all the transaction data. No idea how could I modify it.

Comment: What field of Transaction would be used to know that it's the last one?

Comment: @geoand max value of `id` field in transaction table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first left join gets you the last\max transaction ID for the account. The second left join gets you all the transaction information for that last ID.

```
select ac.*, lasttrans.*
from Account ac 
left join (select acc_id, max(id) as id from Transaction group by acc_id) transmax 
     on ac.id = transmax.acc_id
left join Transaction lasttrans on lasttrans.id = transmax.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try by joining the Account table with only those acc_ids of your Transaction  table that correspond to the maximum ID per acc_id:

```
      select ac.*, t.* from Account ac left join (select acc_id, max(id) from Transaction group by acc_id) trans on ac.id = trans.acc_id left join Transaction t on trans.id=t.id
```

Comment: unable to fetch the field like transaction amount etc since a group by is used.

Comment: Please add explanation about the key aspects of the one-line solution that you have provided.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: is  transaction amount, etc. a field of your  Transaction table?

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar: if you need the other columns of Transaction to be fetched, I have edited the query with the third join. Probably, not the most optimal solution, but I cannot see the other one

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `aggregate` function along with `group by`

```
select * from 
from Account ac left join Transaction trans 
on ac.id = trans.acc_id
where trans.id in (select max(id) from trans group by ac.id)
```

id or date which ever the is the column that you wanna get the `max` of..

Comment: since we're using group by on ac.id we can't other columns in this query like a transaction amount or so. We can just get tran id/date using max func.

Comment: Nope... just a issue when i took count. sometimes there is no transaction then that data is not listed

Comment: its failing because of the where clause

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are expecting?

```
with acc as
(select 1 acc_id, 'name1' acc_name from dual union
select 2 acc_id, 'name2' acc_name from dual union
select 3 acc_id, 'name3' acc_name from dual),
trans as
(select 1 trans_id, 1 trans_acc_id, 'transaction detail 1' transdtl from dual
union
select 2 trans_id, 1 trans_acc_id, 'transaction detail 2' transdtl from dual
union
select 3 trans_id, 1 trans_acc_id, 'transaction detail 3' transdtl from dual
union
select 4 trans_id, 3 trans_acc_id, 'transaction detail 4' transdtl from dual
union
select 5 trans_id, 5 trans_acc_id, 'transaction detail 5' transdtl from dual
)
select * from acc, trans
where acc.acc_id = trans.trans_acc_id 
and trans.trans_id in  (select max(trans_id) from trans inner_trans where 
inner_trans.trans_acc_id = acc.acc_id)
```

The response would be :

```
ACC_ID|ACC_NAME|TRANS_ID|TRANS_ACC_ID|TRANSDTL
1   |name1  |3  |1  |transaction detail 3
3   |name3  |4  |3  |transaction detail 4
```

Comment: This query fetches only accounts which have atleast one transaction in trans table. Do you need details of accounts which do not have any transaction also?